How to get font family name using cget
I'm using the following code:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font
root = Tk()
root.title("Font window")
root.geometry("500x500")

my_font = Font(
    family = 'Helvetica',
    size = 30,
    weight = 'bold',
    slant = 'roman',
    underline = 1,
    overstrike = 0
)
my_label = Label(root, text="Peter Pan", fg="Green", bg="White", font = my_font)

value = my_label.cget("text")
print(value)

my_label.pack()
root.mainloop()

This works, however how do I get the font family value or font size value?

Have you tried cget("font") ?

You can use cget to get the string name of the font associated with the label. For example, when I run your code, print(my_label.cget("font")) will print "font1". To convert that to the font object you have to import nametofont from tkinter.font. With that, you can get information about the font.
from tkinter.font import nametofont
...
font_name = my_label.cget("font")
font_object = nametofont(font_name)
print(font_object.cget("family"), font_object.cget("size"))


Thanks - this works and returns the actual font name

In your current code, you're using the Label widget and setting the font using a Font object. To retrieve the font family or font size from the Label widget, you can use the cget method with the "font" option. my_label.cget("font") will return a string like 'Helvetica 30 bold roman', which contains the complete font details.
To extract the font family, you can use the actual ("family")  method from the Font object.Similarly, to get the font size, you can use actual("size") from the Font object.

In this specific case calling my_label.cget("font') will not return a string like "Helvetica 30 bold roman". It will return the name of the font object.

Bryan is correct - it does not return the font name - it returns "Font1"

You have to use cget("font"), as John Gordon mentioned in the comments.  This allows you to get any option set for the font.
This options include:

font
name
exists
weight
slant
family
underline
overstrike

Full documentation

This is only partly correct. calling cget("font") will only return a string representing the font object, rather than the font object itself.

Bryan is correct - it does not return the font name - it returns "Font1"
